# How to refactor this method?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I've written a method to merge a date interval with another date interval if the start of interval is equal to the end of the other interval.

```
def merge
  slots.each do |slot|
    if self.start == slot.end
      slot.end = self.end
      slot.save
      return self
    elsif self.end == slot.start
      slot.start = self.start
      slot.save
      return self
    end
  end
  self.save
end
```

`self` is the interval that I want to merge it with any of the intervals that exist in the `slots` array. 
What is the best way to refactor this method?

I tried to turn it into something like this with no success:

```
def merge
  slots.each do |slot|
    if slot.one_bound == slot.other_bound
      slot.other_bound = self.other_bound
      slot.save
      return self
    end
  end
  self.save
end
```

Comment: Could you explain what this method is supposed to do? What is `slot` and what is `self`?

Comment: OK, I updated my question.

Comment: Presumably, `merge` is an instance method of the class `Range`. Is that correct? `slots` appears to be a local variable containing an array of ranges,  If so, that will raise an exception because `slots` has neither been passed to the method `merge` nor defined in `merge`. If `self = 1..3` and `slots = [0..1, 3..5]` do you want to replace the value of self (and return the same) to `0..5`? If `self = 1..2` and `slots` is the same , do you wish to return `0..2`? What do you want returned when `self = 1..2` and `slots = [3..5, 5..7]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more readable:

```
def merge
  slots.each do |slot|
    if start_the_same_as_end_for?(slot)
      slot.end = self.end
    elsif end_the_same_as_start_for?(slot)
      slot.start = self.start
    end

    slot.save
  end
end

private

def start_the_same_as_end_for?(slot)
  self.start == slot.end
end

def end_the_same_as_start_for?(slot)
  self.end == slot.start
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [gem](https://github.com/monocle/range_operators) to add operators to Range :

```
# gem install range_operators
require 'date'
require 'range_operators'

range1 = Date.new(2014, 5, 10) .. Date.new(2014, 8, 10)
range2 = Date.new(2014, 8, 10) .. Date.new(2014, 8, 20)
range3 = Date.new(2014, 8, 11) .. Date.new(2014, 8, 20)

puts range1 + range2
#=> 2014-05-10..2014-08-20
```

As a bonus, it also works if the second range is right after the first range :

```
puts range1 + range3
#=> 2014-05-10..2014-08-20
```

Note that `Range#` returns an array of ranges. If this array has only one element, it means the ranges have been merged :

```
result = range1 + range2
if result.size == 1 then
  # save result.first 
end
```